# How to get total memory used in MB by nodejs process with bash on centos

Tags: node.js, bash, memory, sh

Somehow with PM2 imonit, it can display CPU and Memory used by nodeJS process.
[image: my ss]

How can I get the same value (MegaBytes) in total with bash scripting on centos?

This what I've :

```
admin@cent7a ~/w/s/app> ps aux | grep -i node
admin    24722  0.3  2.0 2509600 74632 ?       Ssl  18:36   0:09 node /home/admin/www/survey/app/app.js
admin    24880  0.0  1.0 926516 39196 pts/0    Sl+  18:37   0:00 node /bin/pm2 logs
admin    26556  5.5 10.3 2786552 374500 ?      Sl   18:49   2:00 node /home/admin/www/survey/app/index.js
admin    27938  4.1 11.0 2870796 398924 ?      Sl   18:59   1:06 node /home/admin/www/survey/app/index.js
admin    32015  0.0  0.0 112812   988 pts/1    R+   19:26   0:00 grep --color=auto -i node
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I've edit the question. sorry, that's only what I know, still haven't got an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `ps -o rss` to view real memory usage

With the `-o` option, or `--format`, you can specify a user-defined format that will let you view the memory usage of a process (percentage of total memory). `rss` is used here to display memory usage.

[command breakdown](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ps+-axo+pid%2Crss%2Ccommand)

```sh
# without pid and command you'll just have memory which isn't useful
# does not work with -u or -v, you'll need to specify all format options yourself
ps -axo pid,rss,command
```

## What if you don't want to specify each part of the format?

You can also choose to only provide a `-v` option to `ps` and it will display the real memory usage along with other related stats and the default columns as well.

[command breakdown](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ps+-axv)

```sh
# does not work with -u
ps -axv
```

### How to convert this value into Megabytes?

You can take the value provided from `ps -o rss` and divide it by `1024` with `bc`. The following is an example of this pipeline.

```sh
echo "scale=2; $(ps -o rss <PID> | tail -1) / 1024" | bc -l
```

#### Breakdown

```sh
# scale=2; is for `bc` to truncate the number of digits after the decimal point
echo "scale=2; $(

# Gets the real memory usage of your process
# (but still contains column headers line)
  ps -o rss <PID> |

# Remove the column headers by grabbing the last line
  tail -1

# Convert from Kilobytes to Megabytes
) / 1024" |

# Handle the math (-l allows it to do fractional division)
bc -l
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, i've test your code, how to get the sum of (eg. nginx) memory used without know or put an PID